# Decision tree in r

Tags: r, tree, machine-learning, decision-tree

my dataset is :

```
x=data.frame(v1=c(97 ,  97 ,  85 ,  84 ,  90 ,  80 ,  81 ,  90 ,  80,    70,    90 ,   90,    90    ,95  ,  88 ,   99),
+ v2=c(99  , 91  , 91   ,83  , 99  , 95  , 74  , 88  , 82   , 80   , 96  ,  87  ,  92 ,   96  ,  88,    95),
+ v3=c( 89   ,93  , 87  , 80  , 96  , 96  , 75  , 90  , 78,    86  ,  92    ,88  ,  80,    88   , 98    ,98),
+ v4=c( 89  , 97   ,91  , 86  , 95 ,  95  , 89 ,  88  , 75,    82   , 99,    92  ,  95,    92   , 90,    98),
+ v5=c( 99   ,90  , 93   ,91  , 90  , 90  , 77  , 92  , 85,    76  ,  90,    96  ,  90,    90   , 90,    92))
> x
   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  97 99 89 89 99
2  97 91 93 97 90
3  85 91 87 91 93
4  84 83 80 86 91
5  90 99 96 95 90
6  80 95 96 95 90
7  81 74 75 89 77
8  90 88 90 88 92
9  80 82 78 75 85
10 70 80 86 82 76
11 90 96 92 99 90
12 90 87 88 92 96
13 90 92 80 95 90
14 95 96 88 92 90
15 88 88 98 90 90
16 99 95 98 98 92
```

I used `rpart` package to apply decision tree as follows :

```
# Classification Tree with rpart
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(v5 ~ v1+v2+v3+v4,
              method="class", data=x)

printcp(fit) # display the results 

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = v5 ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4, data = x, method = "class")

Variables actually used in tree construction:
character(0)

Root node error: 9/16 = 0.5625

n= 16 

    CP nsplit rel error xerror xstd
1 0.01      0         1      0    0


> summary(fit) # detailed summary of splits

Call:
rpart(formula = v5 ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4, data = x, method = "class")
  n= 16 

    CP nsplit rel error xerror xstd
1 0.01      0         1      0    0

Node number 1: 16 observations
  predicted class=90  expected loss=0.5625  P(node) =1
    class counts:     1     1     1     7     1     2     1     1     1
   probabilities: 0.062 0.062 0.062 0.438 0.062 0.125 0.062 0.062 0.062
```

**plot tree**

```
 # plot tree 
 plot(fit, uniform=TRUE, 
+      main="Classification Tree ")

Error in plot.rpart(fit, uniform = TRUE, main = "Classification Tree ") : 
  fit is not a tree, just a root

 text(fit, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.8)

Error in text.rpart(fit, use.n = TRUE, all = TRUE, cex = 0.8) : 
  fit is not a tree, just a root
```

what is my wrong while I applied `rpart` ? why it give me error with tree plot?  how to fix this error  Error :

fit is not a tree, just a root

Comment: Do you realize your tree does not have any splits and consists of a single node?

Answer (score 2):

You use method="class" if you are building a classification tree and method="anova" if you are building a regression tree.  It looks like you have a continuous response, so you should be building a regression tree (i.e. method="anova").

Comment: Ryan , I run` method= "anova"` and it give me the same error `fit is not a tree just a root`

Comment: I think the problem in plotting the tree stems from the fact that the model does not make any splits.  In your output, nsplit = 0, thus there is no branching in the tree.  Because of this, there is nothing to plot.  I think that is where the error is coming from.  That doesn't mean you have a problem in your model though.

Comment: Ryan could you tell me how to fix it.

Comment: I suggest looking over the documentation on rpart.  You will find different parameters you can change, if you are comfortable doing so.  For example, if you are okay with changing the default value of cp from .01 to something else, then the regression tree might choose the best model that actually makes splits.  Then you would have a tree to plot

Answer (score 0):

You are using the RPART's default control parameters. With your data set RPART is unable to adhere to default values and create a tree (branch splitting)

```
rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = round(minsplit/3), cp = 0.01, 
              maxcompete = 4, maxsurrogate = 5, usesurrogate = 2, xval = 10,
              surrogatestyle = 0, maxdepth = 30, ...)
```

Adjust the control parameters according to the data set.

e.g :

```
t <- rpart(formula = v5 ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4, data = x, method = anova",control =rpart.control(minsplit = 1,minbucket=1, cp=0))
```

But be aware this could create an over fitting decision tree.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code with your `x` data frame and got a tree as shown below:

```
library(rpart)
library(rattle)
library(rpart.plot)
library(RColorBrewer)

fit <- rpart(v5 ~ v1+v2+v3+v4,
             method="anova", 
             data=x,
             control = rpart.control(minsplit = 6, cp = 0.01))
fancyRpartPlot(fit)  #from RColorBrewer package
```

[image]

Note that your method should be **anova** as *v5* is a continuous variable, and you have to override the control parameters `control = rpart.control(...)` to adjust the depth of the tree.